# Issue license without an order

Tags: commerce, users, files

I'd like to issue free Commerce Licenses to files for users of certain roles without creating orders.

I haven't been able to find a tool for this in the Commerce License UI. Have I missed it? Or is it possible to create such a tool without having to code?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution applies to your specific case, but on my site, I award a role with the license.  So, when I want to "give away" a license without creating an order, I just add the role to the account.  Or, I use the Rules and Flag modules to flag a user (and there is a rule that automatically adds the role).

If you really wanted a license, you could also probably use Rules to create an order and fill it with dummy information, then award the license that way.  Commerce License has decent Rules module integration, so you can get pretty far without any coding.

Comment: Sorry about the long wait @patrick kenny. Nice simple solution doing it as a role. I'd still like to do it on a more granular level. I've got hundreds of licenses and ideally I could enter a list of emails in some UI to send out invites for people to redeem a free license for a specific file... Will update this thread if I find the solution

Comment: @KristofferRom Using a role-based approach, you could do this with the Rules module-- you can add and remove roles in rules.  If it's always the same file, you could make a specific role just for that.